# CSS: Aligning Images in IE vs. Firefox or Chrome - Image size all screwed up

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, alignment

Kind of a frustrating question for me.

Here's the link. Try it in IE, Chrome and Firefox.  The latter two are fine and the image is aligned to the right and appears as 375x500.  But in IE, the image aligns to the right, but appears as 15x500.

http://www.themoneygoround.com/2011/04/intc-intel-shows-up-strong-afterhours.html

When I look at the View Source in IE, the image width and height should be 375x500, but that's not what displays.  The image is aligned to the right as expected, but shrunk to 15x500.  Thanks for any thoughts...

Here is the CSS

```
p img {
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    }

img.centered {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }

img.alignright {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0 0 2px 7px;
    display: inline;
    }

img.alignleft {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0 7px 2px 0;
    display: inline;
    }

.alignright {
    float: right;
    }

.alignleft {
    float: left;
    }
/* End Images */
```

Comment: Having problems getting IE to perform like the other far more modern browsers is expected and the norm.

Comment: I'm confused. The image seems the same in IE9 but the flash stuff on the right is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem as well with IE 8.  The trouble is your `max-width` property for the `<img>`.  IE will not render a `max-width` correctly with the XHTML doctype (which you appear to be using).  You can either remove the `max-width` or use a doctype which will trigger standards mode in IE.  I recommend the HTML5 doctype as per [this article](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-doctype/).

Comment: Thank you, D Gauer.  Removing max-width resolved the problem.  I also changed to the HTML5 doctype, which didn't resolve it but is probably a good idea going forward.  Thank you again.

Comment: @muck Glad that worked!  If you get a chance to "accept" my answer, I'd appreciate it.  Happy developing.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I see about 14 javascript errors in IE when I pull that up stating 'null' is null or not an object.  Maybe start there?

***EDIT: By the way, I was in IE8***

**Working Solution:**

I removed the `<p class="alignright"></p>` that was wrapping the image in question, and it worked like a charm.

View in my ***[working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/qUyXn/)***.

Comment: I believe this only works because the max-width is now no longer referring to the <img> because the CSS is refering to "p img".

Comment: @D Gauer - possibly, but it does work and allows the OP to move on without any other mess.  I don't know why the max-width is there to begin with really, but not my app. =D